# Puma or Unicorn VS Webbrick load test benchmark shows no improvement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, performance, heroku

**The Setup**

Ok, I am running a rails application on Heroku(free tier).

I have 2 separate application releases, lets call them *Staging* and *Fake-Production*.

In *Staging*, I am using Webbrick as the server. My `Procfile` is

```
web: rails s -p $PORT
```

In *Fake-Production*, I am using Puma as the server. My `Procfile` is

```
bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

I have configured puma to run with 2 workers and 1 thread per worker.
`config/puma.rb` is defined below (taken from [Heroku's Setting up Puma Webserver](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#config))

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 1)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  # Worker specific setup for Rails 4.1+
  # See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-    with-the-puma-web-server#on-worker-boot
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

My `database.yml` is configured to have a connection pool of 20.

**The Test**

In order to do the load testing, I used ApacheBench tool from my laptop to hit an API endpoint. The API basically does a very simple database query to return a fixed amount of records (does not change).

I hit both deployments with the following code:

```
ab -n 1000 -c 100 https://<some heroku endpoint>?access_token=f73f50514c
```

**The Results**

The results here are the most surprising. I was expecting the Puma deployment to comepletely trash the Webbrick deployment, but in reality, it was almost the same. I tried hitting different API endpoints as well as different combination of Puma workers and threads (at one point, It was 4 workers and 5 threads) and yet there wasnt any visible improvements.

***Webbrick Results***

```
Server Software:        WEBrick/1.3.1
Server Hostname:        webbrick-build.herokuapp.com
Server Port:            443
SSL/TLS Protocol:       TLSv1,DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA,2048,128

Document Path:          /api/v1/packages?access_token=f73f50514c6
Document Length:        488 bytes

Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   21.484 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      995000 bytes
HTML transferred:       488000 bytes
Requests per second:    46.55 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       2148.360 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       21.484 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          45.23 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:      714 1242 278.1   1214    2012
Processing:   248  842 493.6    699    2883
Waiting:      247  809 492.3    677    2876
Total:       1072 2085 643.5   1929    4845

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%   1929
  66%   2039
  75%   2109
  80%   2168
  90%   2622
  95%   3821
  98%   4473
  99%   4646
 100%   4845 (longest request)
```

Memory Impact

```
source=web.1 dyno=heroku.1234567899 sample#memory_total=198.41MB sample#memory_rss=197.60MB sample#memory_cache=0.30MB sample#memory_swap=0.51MB sample#memory_pgpgin=103879pages sample#memory_pgpgout=53216pages
```

***Puma Results***(More or less the same regardless of Worker/Thread count)

```
Server Software:        Cowboy
Server Hostname:        puma-build.herokuapp.com
Server Port:            443
SSL/TLS Protocol:       TLSv1,DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA,2048,128

Document Path:          /api/v1/packages?access_token=fb7168c147adc2ccd83b2
Document Length:        489 bytes

Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   23.299 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      943000 bytes
HTML transferred:       489000 bytes
Requests per second:    42.92 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       2329.949 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       23.299 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          39.52 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:      743 1304 283.9   1287    2092
Processing:   253  951 740.3    684    5353
Waiting:      253  898 729.0    627    5196
Total:       1198 2255 888.0   1995    7426

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%   1995
  66%   2085
  75%   2213
  80%   2444
  90%   3755
  95%   4238
  98%   5119
  99%   5437
 100%   7426 (longest request)
```

Memory Impact(4 workers, 5 threads)

```
source=web.1 dyno=heroku.1234567890 sample#memory_total=406.75MB sample#memory_rss=406.74MB sample#memory_cache=0.00MB sample#memory_swap=0.00MB sample#memory_pgpgin=151515pages sample#memory_pgpgout=47388pages
```

Based on the snippets above, sometimes the Puma deployment will be faster than Webbrick, while other times it can be slower (as shown in the snippet). Even if it is much faster, the speed is not significant, probably only increase by 1-5 requests/sec.

My question here is, what am i doing wrong? Is my database pool somehow at fault?Am i benchmarking it wrongly? Am I using Puma wrongly?

***EDIT:***

Highest CPU Load for Puma (5 worker and 5 threads each)

```
source=web.1 dyno=heroku.123456789 sample#load_avg_1m=2.98
```

Most of the time however, its either 0.00 or smaller than 0.1.

On top of that, the only code that is called in the controller is:

```
@package = Package.all
```

Immediately after, it is followed by rendering of the JSON response which is declared in HAML.

Btw, Package.all only returns about 5 records.

***EDIT 2:***

UNICORN RESULTS

Implemented Unicorn according to . Running 3 unicorn workers.

```
Server Software:        Cowboy
Server Hostname:        unicorn-build.herokuapp.com
Server Port:            443
SSL/TLS Protocol:       TLSv1,DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA,2048,128

Document Path:          /api/v1/packages?access_token=f73f50514c6b8a3ea
Document Length:        488 bytes

Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   22.311 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      942000 bytes
HTML transferred:       488000 bytes
Requests per second:    44.82 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       2231.135 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       22.311 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          41.23 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:      846 1326 294.5   1304    2720
Processing:   245  627 342.8    540    3061
Waiting:      244  532 313.6    470    3057
Total:       1232 1954 463.0   1874    4875

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%   1874
  66%   2016
  75%   2161
  80%   2250
  90%   2466
  95%   2799
  98%   3137
  99%   3901
 100%   4875 (longest request)
```

One thing ive noticed is that running the same ab load test code several times will return different "Requests per seconds". This applies to both Unicorn and Puma. For both Unicorn and Puma, the best "Requests per seconds" is about 48-50 while the worst is about 25-33.

Either way, it still does not make sense. Why are'nt either Puma or Unicorn crushing Webbrick?

Comment: Lately puma has many issues with memory leaking and i was forced to switch server to phusion passenger 5.023. Check it's benchmark if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I trust that you have followed Heroku's [Deploying Rails Applications with the Puma Web Server](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server) guide thoroughly.

My guess is that your test environment minimizes multi-threading advantages, or the HTTP server is bottle-necked by the SQL database.

Your API calls, especially if they cache database results, can be CPU intensive. Having 10 threads is no advantage when the CPU is used 100% by only 1. Managing the threads can actually hinder the performance in this case.

Multi-threading is useful when your worker threads are waiting a long time for resources (databases, files, etc.), instead of using the CPU.

The second possibility is that your HTTP server is constrained by the database. It may be that WEBrick is moving as fast as the database is allowing it, leaving no room for improvement by switching to a better performing HTTP server.

You should give [this](http://www.madebymarket.com/blog/dev/ruby-web-benchmark-report.html) comprehensive benchmark report a read.

You will notice that Puma isn't one of the speediest Rails HTTP servers. If all you care about is speed, try [Unicorn](http://unicorn.bogomips.org), or [Torquebox 4](https://github.com/torquebox/torquebox/tree/torqbox) if using *JRuby*.

Here's a [guide](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2013/2/27/unicorn_rails) on how to setup Unicorn on Heroku.

Comment: I dont think my process is CPU bound. 
The highest ive seen the CPU load is:
    source=web.1 dyno=heroku.123456789 sample#load_avg_1m=2.98

Most of the time however, its either 0.00 or smaller than 0.1.

On top of that, the only code that is called in the controller is:
    @package = Package.all
Immediately after, it is followed by rendering of the JSON response which is declared in HAML.

Btw, Package.all only returns about 5 records.

I will try your suggestion on Unicorn and inspect the link you provided further and then get back to you. 

Thanks!

Comment: It might very well be database constrained then. Your DB can serve only as many requests per second. This can constrain your web server. Maybe WEBrick is moving as fast as the database is allowing it, leaving no room for improvement.

Comment: Ill try using Unicorn first, and then Ill try just hitting a simple "hello world" page.
Man, something like this just makes me not be able to sleep in peace. Just cant seem to make sense of it. :S
Ill let you know.

Comment: Nop, hitting an index page that does nothing but load HTML and CSS and Webbrick still keeps up with Puma or Unicorn with any number of workers.
Ill probably create a brand new scaffold app and test this again.

Comment: @Tikiboy I ran into the same issue(?) my performance across Webbrick and Unicorn seems to be pretty much the same as seen from apache bench tests. Did you find anything that lead to something more conclusive?

Comment: Hey @Projjol, unfortunately no. So far my understanding of performance improvements remains at the theoratical level. I even created a temp project with all 3 different implementation and benchmarked them (Webbrick, Puma and Unicorn). I intended to create a follow up question while linking the temp project for others to try but i got sidetracked. 

If you do eventually find out conclusive details about this, do let me know, I am greatly interested in finding out as well. :D